# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Configuration can't be altered once the class has been compiled or used

Tags: spring-mvc

Iam inserting some data into DB with simpleJdbcInsert in spring , it works fine for first step (i mean for first insertion ) , when i try yo save the data for second time iam getting exception as :org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Configuration can't be altered once the class has been compiled or used."

Can any one help me out in this.

Answer (score 7):

This exception usually happens when you try to config(again) a **compiled** simpleJdbcInsert.

**compiled** means you have instantiated a simpleJdbcInsert instance and set up **data source** and **table name** already.
Once an simpleJdbcInsert instance is **compiled**, you should not re-config it again; for instance, set another table name. Create a new simpleJdbcInsert instace if you need to do so.

To get a comprehensive understanding about how **simpleJdbcInsert** works, take a look into source code of **simpleJdbcInsert** and **AbstractJdbcInsert**. especially the method **compile()** in **AbstractJdbcInsert.java**

Comment: Hi cannot i insert more records being on the same page, on first insertion data is getting inserted , but after navigating and again coming to insertion page , this kind of error iam getting. could u please tell is thier any configureation required to insert more records

Comment: are you inserting the the data into same table after page page navigation? Please attache your code to let people reproduce the issue and figure out where goes wrong.

Comment: @Resource(name="dataSource")
 public void setSimpleJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
  this.simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource); and other paramertes set into Map, simpleJdbcInsert.execute(parameterMap).
  this.simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource);
 }
 code to insert into DB:
 this.simpleJdbcInsert.withTableName("MOVIE_INFO");
  Map<String,Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
  parameterMap.put("MOVIE_NAME", movie.getMovieName());

Comment: did any one come across this kind of issue. I saw AbstractJdbcInsert ,in which isCompile method checks for this is compile variable is set true this exception is thrown

Comment: remove ** this.simpleJdbcInsert.withTableName("MOVIE_INFO");**. withTableName does nothing rather than just setting table name. And please refer to my answer, you cannot set table name multiple times to same SimpleJdbcInsert instance.

Comment: Thanks for response , if i remove the withTableName(), then how to give table Name, i tried with setTable. Still the same exception . Where can i give the table NAme

Comment: in your case, the table name is **reset** to the same SimpleJdbcInsert instance every time after page navigation. One workaround is to create new SimpleJdbcInsert instance everytime, but this is not recommended. Or you can make your code a bit smarter such that it can set table name only once. If it requires big change to the existing code, then simply add a check before withTableName() as follows. **if(!simpleJdbcInsert.isCompiled()){simpleJdbcInsert.withTableName("MOVIE_INFO")}**

Comment: Okay , i will try to set the table name only once.Thanks for replying back.